# Replacing a column / row of a sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm writing a sparse matrix factorization routine in python. I need to update a sparse matrix by replacing a column / row.

For example

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = csc_matrix(np.random.rand(5,5))
>>> A[:,1] = [1,2,3,4,5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py", line 125, in __setitem__
    x = x.reshape(i.shape)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 25 into shape (5,1)
>>>
```

But this results in an error. Is there a way I can do this?

EDIT: It seems to depend on the version scipy I use. The code works when I use the version on my laptop  (1.6.1) but fails for the one on the server I'm using (1.4.1)

Comment: What's the error? It works for me with no error

Comment: I edited it to show the full error.

Comment: This does not fail for me, it works as expected.

Comment: the code i nor failing on that line , as you can see in the error message , the code `x = x.reshape(i.shape)` is failing

Comment: Yes but that's part of the scipy library code. I didn't write that. So as far as my code is concerned it's the "A[:,1] = [1,2,3,4,5]" line that causes the error.

Comment: As you discovered, whether or not it works will depend on which version of SciPy you are using.  You can check which version you are using with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.

Comment: The current scipy version is 1.8.0